# Calling stored proc with exec statement with CRLF in parameter

Tags: t-sql

I want to call a stored proc with a parameter that contains a string that includes a CRLF.

I am actually calling the SP from an MSAccess Pass Through query. I build the exec statement and it passes it through to SQL in the query

Any ideas?

Malcolm

EDIT: The parameter is to be the body of an email used in the SP.

After "Lester employee:" is a newline.

```
wit_data_driven_subscription_2parameters 'Invoice', _
    'malcolm-smith@bigpond.com', _
    'payroll@lester.com.au', _
    "Invoice Reprint As Requested", _
    "Attached is the invoice reprint       you requested for Lester employee:

Jeff Rogers", 'CapturedInvoice', '120744'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TSQL accepts line break characters within string literals... In other words, this is valid:

```
EXEC storedProcedure 'My parameter
with a line break'
```

It depends on how you generate this string in MSAccess... from vba (ms access).. you can build the query like this:

```
Dim query as String
query = "EXEC storedProcedure 'My parameter" + vbCrLf + "with a line break'"
```

I don't remember a great deal about access but if you can pass in values using parameters rather than string literals then you avoid this problem, and you avoid plenty of other problems such as SQL injection

Comment: There is no reason to sign your posts; doing so is redundant (your screen name is on every post) and doing it repeatedly could lead to suspension.  I suggest to do not continue this practice.

Answer (score 0):

In your `exec yourSP` statement, have something like:

`exec yourStoredProcedure @yourParam = replace(@yourCRLF, '')`

I don't know what the CRLF looks like in your string (`\r\n` maybe???), but you can replace `@yourCRLF` variable with the actual CRLF char/string.

Comment: I dont want to get rid of the newline. It is for body of an email.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be an email issue and not actually a SQL problem. I had this problem on HTML emails in the past. Replace your CrLf with an HTML break tag `<BR>`.